# JSF custom tag sub attribute

Tags: jsf, tags

I am creating a custom tag for editing metadata of a book. The tag declaration is like that:

```
    <tag>
        <tag-name>BookMetaDataEditor</tag-name>
        <source>BookMetaDataEditor</source>
        <attribute>
            <name>bookMetadata</name>
            <type>domain.book.BookMetaData</type>
        </attribute>
    </tag>
```

And the implementation of the tag looks like this:

```
    <ui:composition>
        <p:panelGrid>
                <p:outputLabel value="Title"/>
                <p:inputText value="#{bookMetadata.title}"></p:inputText>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </ui:composition>
```

The problem is that no title is displayed and the debugger does not step into the getter method of title. I tried it passing all attributes like title etc. explicitly. The getter part is working but if I edit the title the setter is not called, so I think that the value binding does not work properly back to the bean.

Comment: Did you run your application in development mode? Any errors then?

Comment: @Kukeltje I did, apparently I had a typo. However the setter is not called what so ever.

Comment: Then there is are only three things remaining... Try with plain jsf components, Provide version info (jsf api +impl and PrimeFaces version. And provide a [mcve].

Comment: I googled around a lot and I think I found the issue. The Backing Bean has a List<BookMetadata> and I display it using a ui:repeat element. Inside said ui:repeat is the above tag. Apparently the binding does not work properly for ui:repeats. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Like mentioned before... [mcve]